# Mongoose Deep Populate, not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a web app, which requires use of `mongoose-deep-populate`, i have installed it using `npm`. But i still get the following error:

```
Error: Plugin was not installed
at Query.deepPopulate (/Users/nikhilb/nodeapp/tracking_app/node_modules/mongoose-deep-populate/lib/plugin.js:30:15)
at /Users/nikhilb/nodeapp/tracking_app/routes/training.js:38:8
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Its says pluggin not installed, but in my `package.json` file it is installed:

```
"mongoose": "^5.0.0",
"mongoose-deep-populate": "^3.0.0"
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have required it as:

```
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the plugin with your schema. For example:

```
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose)

MySchema.plugin(deepPopulate)
```

You can pass options as the second argument if needed.

Comment: i am sorry, i dint get where to register this ?? in the model.js schema?

Comment: Also getting this error: `TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function`

Comment: Yes you would register the plugin in the file where you define your schema.

Comment: TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function
    at createMongoosePromise (/Users/nikhilb/nodeapp/tracking_app/node_modules/mongoose-deep-populate/lib/plugin.js:98:17)

Comment: **Full Error**  
TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function
    at createMongoosePromise (/Users/nikhilb/nodeapp/tracking_app/node_modules/mongoose-deep-populate/lib/plugin.js:98:17)
    at Query.exec (/Users/nikhilb/nodeapp/tracking_app/node_modules/mongoose-deep-populate/lib/plugin.js:67:14)
    at Query.then (/Users/nikhilb/nodeapp/tracking_app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2972:15)
    at /Users/nikhilb/nodeapp/tracking_app/routes/training.js:41:8
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

Comment: Maybe this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561915/node-7-1-0-new-promise-resolver-undefined-is-not-a-function